# jquery nearest element somewhere in dom (fuzzy search)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there built-in jQuery method that allow to find a dom element nearest to another element? By nearest I meant - nearest by minimal length of relative path (XPath for example) from one to another.

Consider following sample (drop-box from Twitter Bootstrap). There are drop-down icon - element with `.JS-ACTIONS` and set of links - element with `.JS-DELETE`, when one of links clicked the progress bar on the drop-down icon should be enabled.

```
<div class='btn-group'>
  <a href='#' class='btn dropdown-toggle JS-ACTIONS' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    <i class='icon-cog'></i>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu pull-right'>
    <li><a href='#' class='JS-DELETE'>Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

One way to do it, use something like

`$(element.currentTarget).parent().parent().find('.JS-ACTIONS').showProgress()`

But I want the JavaScript to be independet from the DOM structure, something like

`$(element.currentTarget).nearest('.JS-ACTIONS').showProgress()`

Is there such a method in jQuery available?

**UPDATE**

The `closest` method of jQuery didn't works, it searches in parents only, it doesn't searches in siblings and other children of parents.

Comment: Seriously, you guessed `.nearest()`, but could'nt find `.closest()` on Google ?

Comment: `.closest` is only relevant here by name, jQuery likes to keep the names short so it isn't called `.closestItselfOrAnyParent` which is what `closest` actually does and has no relevance to OP's problem by itself

Answer (score 2):

You may want [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(element.currentTarget).closest('.JS-ACTIONS').showProgress()
```

Comment: Isn't the `closest` searches in parents only, without going into other children of parents?

Comment: I believe that is correct. If you want the nearest by either parent or sibling you may need something custom.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) it gives you the first appearance of matched element in the hierarchy of ancestors.

```
$(element.currentTarget).closest('.JS-ACTIONS')
```